# How to access group ids for grouped filter operation?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have a data frame containing dates and associated values for three groups as follows.

```
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

data <-
  data.frame(group = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 5),
             date = rep(seq(ymd(20200101), ymd(20200105), by = 1),
                        times = 3),
             value = runif(15))
```

I would like to perform a grouped filter operation in order to extract subsets of the data by date, where the start date varies by group.

```
start_date <- list(a = ymd(20200102), b = ymd(20200104), c = ymd(20200103))
```

I'd like to use the group name to index into the start date list. I try to do the operation as follows, but I get an error message.

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(date >= start_date[[group]])
```

```
Error in app$vspace(new_style$`margin-top` %||% 0) :
  attempt to apply non-function
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

(The alternative to the above procedure is to set the start dates up as a data frame, join the data frame to `data`, and perform an ungrouped filter. This works as intended, but it's less elegant (in my opinion) and I'd prefer to keep the start dates as a list for other reasons.)

```
start_date_2 <- 
  data.frame(group = c("a", "b", "c"), 
             start_date = c(ymd(20200102), ymd(20200104), c = ymd(20200103)))

data %>%
  left_join(start_date_2, by = "group") %>%
  filter(date >= start_date) %>%
  select(-start_date)
```

Comment: `dplyr::group_map()` or `dplyr::group_modify()` will be your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can access the name of the current group(s) by using `cur_group()`. This gives us a tibble with every group being a column containing the current group name, so we need to subset it with `$group`.

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(date >= start_date[[cur_group()$group]])

#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   group date        value
#>   <chr> <date>      <dbl>
#> 1 a     2020-01-02 0.225 
#> 2 a     2020-01-03 0.345 
#> 3 a     2020-01-04 0.110 
#> 4 a     2020-01-05 0.0951
#> 5 b     2020-01-04 0.356 
#> 6 b     2020-01-05 0.345 
#> 7 c     2020-01-03 0.0973
#> 8 c     2020-01-04 0.344 
#> 9 c     2020-01-05 0.418
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can use `purrr`:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data %>% 
  group_split(group) %>% 
  map2(., start_date, ~ filter(.x , date >= .y)) %>% 
  bind_rows()

#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   group date        value
#>   <fct> <date>      <dbl>
#> 1 a     2020-01-02 0.0756
#> 2 a     2020-01-03 0.0535
#> 3 a     2020-01-04 0.338 
#> 4 a     2020-01-05 0.332 
#> 5 b     2020-01-04 0.992 
#> 6 b     2020-01-05 0.356 
#> 7 c     2020-01-03 0.751 
#> 8 c     2020-01-04 0.949 
#> 9 c     2020-01-05 0.778
```

Comment: You could use `group_modify` as well `data %>% group_by(group) %>% group_modify(~ .x %>% filter(date >= start_date[[first(.y$group)]])) %>% ungroup`

Comment: @akrun thanks. That'd be similar to TimTeaFan's answer (in terms of filtering start_date based on current group). I like using `purrr` here; it feels more intuitive, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

We could use a non-equi join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[data.table(date = do.call(c, start_date), 
    group = names(start_date)), on = .(group, date >= date)]
    group       date       value
   <char>     <Date>       <num>
1:      a 2020-01-02 0.003896343
2:      a 2020-01-02 0.052198616
3:      a 2020-01-02 0.866560180
4:      a 2020-01-02 0.576245169
5:      b 2020-01-04 0.531409336
6:      b 2020-01-04 0.383936672
7:      c 2020-01-03 0.041919498
8:      c 2020-01-03 0.363742695
9:      c 2020-01-03 0.856596967
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be:

```
data %>%
    filter(date >= start_date[match(group, names(start_date))])

  group       date      value
1     a 2020-01-02 0.29910439
2     a 2020-01-03 0.08603731
3     a 2020-01-04 0.78913465
4     a 2020-01-05 0.40025848
5     b 2020-01-04 0.87568202
6     b 2020-01-05 0.21065155
7     c 2020-01-03 0.47403618
8     c 2020-01-04 0.74996630
9     c 2020-01-05 0.08386366
```